# Is the T class in generic Class<T> assignable from another class?

Tags: java, generics, class

**Edit**
Since there were many downvotes and people who didn't understand what I'm asking for, I'll rephrase:

How do I find out at runtime what is the class that foo was generified from?

```
public boolean doesClassImplementList(Class<?> genericClass)
{
  // help me fill this in
  // this method should return true if genericClass implements List
  // I can't do this because it doesn't compile:
  return genericClass instanceof List;
}
```

Comment: -1 for posting an example that doesn't compile. And one that could be answered in two lines of code.

Comment: It could be answered if I knew the answer, but I don't and I looked in Class documentation and failed to find it.

Comment: It would be answered if you wrote examples that compiled. Start with foo = Integer.class and go from there.

Comment: That what happens sometimes when you copy paste code and try to simplify it for posting. Fixed.

Comment: Still, I don't understand the downvotes. I'm asking a legitimate question about java's type system / reflection.

Comment: foo could be int.class. But anyway, I can't find a meaningful question here.

Comment: How can I extract from foo the class it's generified on. Integer.class, that is. I will edit.

Comment: Still not getting the clarified question. x = foo; would work.

Comment: return List.class.isAssignableFrom(genericClass);

Comment: much better example, and you got an answer ... downvote removed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Class.isAssignableFrom`

Comment: I get it now, it is really a silly question.

I think what confused me is Java's concept of generics. I'm still not quite used to it (as opposed to .Nets').

Answer (score 0):

you cannot in Java ([type erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html))

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Class.forName( "fully_qualified_name" ) to generate a Class object, or using the .getClass() method on an already instantiated object. Also, for int types, the class is defined in the Integer.TYPE property.

I need a little more clarification of what you are attempting to do, match the same type? You can use a number of methods, what is the end goal?

Ok, now that you've clarified... heres some help ... just pass in a class..

```
public boolean doesClassImplementList(Class genericClass)
{
  // help me fill this in
  // this method should return true if genericClass implements List
  // I can't do this because it doesn't compile:

  //this will give you a a list of class this class implements
  Class[] classesImplementing = genericClass.getInterfaces();

  //loop through this array and test for:
  for(int i=0; i<classesImplementing.length; i++) {
   if (classesImplementing[i].getName().equals("java.util.List")) {
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The questioner does actually use Integer.class in the "question".

Comment: Nice loop. Why didn't you use:  List.class.isAssignableFrom(genericClass); instead?

Tom - I see no reference to Integer.class in the question.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of calling that function - hence why Tom's answer is better.

Just shows that there are lots of ways to do the same thing. Of course, some ARE better than others.

The Integer.class reference is from before he edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

`Class<Integer>` is a type declaration, you can't assign it to a variable, as you are doing on your first line.

`Class<Integer>` is basically a way of referencing the Integer type, so you can pass it as a parameter. It does affect some methods (such as cast) but it is basically a way of providing a generic parameter to a method and associate it with a type.

For example:

```
public <T> T someMethod(Object someObject, Class<T> castTo) {
     return castTo.cast(someObject);
}
```